# bootstrap classes conflicting with Liferay portlet preferences

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, liferay-6, portlet

I experience difficulties to properly display my portlet's preferences (Liferay 6.2.0 server).
All I d like is ti have the top right corner window to correctly display.

I have setupped my Portletpreferences according to internet's tutorials.
If I click the top right corner, click configuration, then setup, my preferences page displays and it just works fine.

However, most of my portlet's JSP use Bootstrap... and unfortunately, there seems to be a conflict between bootstrapp css classes and the portlet preferences page (designed by Liferay).
So if I click setup (right top button) into a non bootstrap page, everything works fine. 
If I click it into a page using bootstrap, portlet preferences not load (nor the look and feel window).

I implemented bootstrap by copying the Bootstrap2.3.2 css and js files into the proper directories inside my portlet project and including them into the jsps.

I thought about spending 2 hours attempting to locate the exact bootstrap class(es) that cause this mess and exclude them from the bootstrap css files.
But I gave up because of browser cache/history issues that return me incoherent results all the time.

A more intelligent method would probably be to call directly the config jsp from my bootstrap pages (without using the top right liferay window).
I can load the page, but using the save buton does not save the options.
I suppose that I would need to add some additional code that is automatically generated by Liferay when calling the config jsp from the right/top window.

MY config.jsp is as follows:

```
<%@include file="/jsp/include/init.jsp"%>


<liferay-portlet:actionURL portletConfiguration="true"
    var="configurationURL" />

<%  

String value1_cfg = GetterUtil.getString(portletPreferences.getValue("--value1--", ""));
String value2_cfg = GetterUtil.getString(portletPreferences.getValue("value2", ""));
...
%>

<aui:form action="<%= configurationURL %>" method="post" name="fm">
    <aui:input name="<%= Constants.CMD %>" type="hidden"
        value="<%= Constants.UPDATE %>" />

...miscellanous form controls that let users change the options....


    <aui:button-row>
        <aui:button type="submit" />
    </aui:button-row>
</aui:form>

<%!
public boolean checkListSelected(String value, String param){
 if(value.equals(param)) 
     return true;
 else
     return false;
}
%>
```

Is there anyone who knows how I could solve this issue?
I m open to any solution :
- better way to import Bootstrap
- isolate the conflicting bootstrap classes if anyone knows which ones are messing
- set the options directly via the config.jsp

thx in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single portlet should never add a CSS framework like Bootstrap which was designed to work for a whole page, because a portlet is only responsible for its own small part and should not interfere with other elements on the page.

*The good news are:* The default Liferay themes resp. AlloyUI integrate Bootstrap 2.3.2 already, so there is no need to include it yourself in your portlet.

In case that you've implemented your own theme then you just need to extend the *styled* or *classic* theme to have the Bootstrap classes included.

Comment: Hi Tobias, if I set an <aui:form>, the offsetX and spanX classes actually work. But I don' t manage to make some other bootstrap classes to work. IE form-control.
For instance, for this control: <aui:input cssClass="form-control span5 "  name="firstName"/>  form-control is not applied but span5 class does apply. Is there anything special to know about this?

Comment: You are still confusing [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) and [Bootstrap 2](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/). The later is the one in Liferay 6.2 which does _not_ include any `form-control` class. There was a major change in Bootstrap 3, most of the classes won't work...

Comment: Thank you for all clarifications Tobias. I got it all working as I want :)